# Determinant from matrix of logarithms

Tags: matrices, logarithms, determinant

Is there a way to get the determinant $\text{Det}(M)$ of a matrix $M$ from the matrix of its logarithms, i.e.

$\Bigg(
\begin{smallmatrix}
\log(M_{00}) & \log(M_{01}) & \ldots \\
\log(M_{10}) & \log(M_{11}) &  \\
\vdots
\end{smallmatrix}\Bigg)\ \ \ \ ?
$

Note that I don't mean the actual [matrix logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix); then I could use the second identity in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154776/proof-of-2-matrix-identities-traces-logs-determinants).

EDIT: I mean if there is a faster way than exponentiating the elements and computing the determinant from scratch.

Comment: well, just apply $e^x$ to every entry and compute the determinant of the resulting matrix :)  [I guess you want something else, but then you should be more specific]

Comment: Haha, good pont:) I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it, determinant being naively $\mathcal{O}(N^3)$. Wishful thinking..?