# What is the $m$th derivative of $\log\left(1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^N n_kx^k\right)$ at $x=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, oeis

Let $n_k$ be integers. Is there a general formula for the Taylor expansion of
$\log(1+\sum_{k=1}^N n_kx^k)$ at $x=0$?
This boils down to find an expression for the $m$th derivative of  $\log(1+\sum_{k=1}^N n_kx^k)$ evaluated $x=0$:
$$
\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\log(1+\sum_{k=1}^N n_kx^k)\Biggr|_{x=0}?
$$

Expanding a (work-in-progress) example like [$-\log(n_3x^3+n_2x^2+n_1x+1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+-log(n_3x%5E3%2Bn_2x%5E2%2Bn_1x%2B1)+at+x%3D0) gives:
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
 x&            (- n_1)\\ 
+ \frac{x^2}2& (+ n_1^2 - 2n_2 ) \\
+ \frac{x^3}3& (- n_1^3 + 3n_2 n_1   - 3n_3) \\
+ \frac{x^4}4& (+ n_1^4 - 4n_2 n_1^2 + 4n_3 n_1  + 2n_2^2 ) \\
+ \frac{x^5}5& (- n_1^5 + 5n_2 n_1^3 - 5n_3n_1^2 - 5n_2^2 n_1  + 5n_3n_2    ) \\
+ \frac{x^6}6& (+ n_1^6 - 6n_2 n_1^4 + 6n_3n_1^3 + 9n_2^2n_1^2 - 12n_3n_2n_1 - 2n_2^3 +3 n_3^2  ) \\
&\dots
\end{array}
$$

Some findings:

- For each $\frac{x^k}k$ the factor in brackets relates to partitions of $k$, which is not very surprising.
- Fixing $k$ then the sign is a term inside a bracket can be determined by the sum of powers of $n_j$: Even sums are negative (e.g. $-n_1^4$) and odd sums positive (e.g. $+5n_2^2n_1$), which reminds me on Möbius' function...
- From one line to the other you can see that multiplying a $n_1$ to the second term adds $1$ to the prefactor (and changes sign)

This looks like a combinatorial thing.[.](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/quotient-rule-for-higher-order-derivatives.289320/)[.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5Em+log(f(x))+%2F+dx%5Em)

Comment: Naturally, the first derivative is $P'(x)/P(x)$ where $P(x)=1+\sum\limits_kn_kx^k$ hence, if the roots $x_j$ of $P$ are distinct, $$\frac1{P(x)}=\sum_j\frac1{P'(x_j)(x-x_j)}=-\sum_j\sum_k\frac{x^k}{P'(x_j)x_j^{k+1}}=-\sum_k\left(\sum_j\frac{1}{P'(x_j)x_j^{k+1}}\right)x^k$$ Since $$P'(x)=\sum_k(k+1)n_{k+1}x^k$$ the expansion of $P'(x)/P(x)$ follows.

Comment: @Did I see, thanks, but doesn't this get pretty messy? A general formula for the individual prefactors seems out of range when I multiply the two infinite expressions...

Comment: @Did isn't your second expansion in the first line an infinite one? The usage of $k$ as index is then confusing because I used a finite $k$ before. If I am right this is a convolution of a infinite and a finite polynomial, right?

Comment: I am sure you will overcome what you say is a cause of possible confusion...

Comment: The general terms seem related to the [Complete Bell Polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Examples_2)

Comment: They actually should be sums of the [Incomplete Bell Polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Generating_function) due to their generating function.

Comment: @Did a more compact version using incomplete Bell polynomials:
$$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\log(1+\sum_{k=1}^N n_kx^k)\Biggr|_{x=0}= m!\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j} B_{m,j}(n_1,n_2,...)$$

Comment: @PaulLeVan did you see Markus' answer? You were right with Bell...

Comment: @draks... Yes, I just didn't have the time at the moment to eke out an answer, and Markus' work was very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another variation of the generalized chain rule besides Faa di Brunos formula is stated as identity (3.56) in H.W. Gould's *[Tables of Combinatorial Identities, Vol. I](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.1.PDF)* and is called:

> **Hoppe Form of Generalized Chain Rule**
>
> Let $D_x$ represent differentiation with respect to $x$ and $t=t(x)$. Hence $D^m_x g(t)$ is the $m$-th derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$. The following holds true
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^m g(t)=\sum_{k=0}^mD_t^kg(t)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}t^{k-j}D_x^mt^j\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In the current situation with $g(t)=\log(t)$ and $t=t(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^Nn_kx^k$
we have 
\begin{align*}
D_t^kg(t)=D_t^k \log(t)=
\begin{cases}
\log(t)&k=0\\
(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(k-1)!}{t^k}&k>0\tag{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
as well as 
\begin{align*}
t(0)=1\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(0)=\log(t(0))=0\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We obtain for $m>0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{D_x^m}&\color{blue}{g(t)\Big|_{x=0}}\\
> &=\left.\sum_{k=0}^m D_t^k\left(\log(t)\right)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}
> \left(t(x)\right)^{k-j}D_x^m\left(t(x)\right)^j\right|_{x=0}\tag{4}\\
> &=\left.\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^{k-1}\frac{(k-1)!}{(t(x))^k}\cdot\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}
> \left(t(x)\right)^{k-j}D_x^m\left(t(x)\right)^j\right|_{x=0}\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\left.\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}
> D_x^m\left(t(x)\right)^j\right|_{x=0}}\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we apply Hoppe's formula with $g(t)=\log(t)$.
- In (5) we start with $k=1$, since when $k=0$ there is a factor $\log(t(0))=0$ according to (3). Consequently we can also start with $j=1$. We also use the $k$-th derivative of $\log$ according to (2).
- In (6) we do some simplifications and use $t(0)=1$ according to (3).

> Let's look at a small example in order to see formula (6) in action:
>
> **Example: $m=3, t(x)=1+n_1x+n_2x^2+n_3x^3$**
>
> Some preparatory work:
>
> \begin{align*}
> D_x^3t(x)\big|_{x=0}&=6n_3\\
> D_x^3(t(x))^2\big|_{x=0}&=12(n_1n_2+n_3)\tag{7}\\
> D_x^3(t(x))^3\big|_{x=0}&=6(n_1^3+6n_1n_2+3n_3)\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{D_x^3\log(t(x))}&=\left.\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}D_x^3\left(t(x)\right)^j\right|_{x=0}\\
> &=\left.1\left(\binom{1}{1}D_x^3\left(t(x)\right)\right)\right|_{x=0}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{2}\left.\left(\binom{2}{1}D_x^3\left(t(x)\right)-\binom{2}{2}D_x^3\left(t(x)\right)^2\right)\right|_{x=0}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{3}\left.\left(\binom{3}{1}D_x^3\left(t(x)\right)
> -\binom{3}{2}D_x^3\left(t(x)\right)^2+\binom{3}{3}D_x^3\left(t(x)\right)^3\right)\right|_{x=0}\\
> &=\left(6n_3\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(2\cdot 6n_3-12(n_1n_2-n_3)\right)\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{3}\left(3\cdot 6n_3-3\cdot 12(n_1n_2+n_3)+6(n_1^3+6n_1n_2+3n_3)\right)\\
> &\color{blue}{=2n_1^3-6n_1n_2+6n_3}
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with OPs expression.

**[Add-on 2017-04-23]** According to OPs comment we add a formula for $D_x^m(t(x))^j$ to support the preparatory work in the example above.

> We apply the *[multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)* to 
>   \begin{align*}
> (t(x))^j=\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^Nn_kx^k\right)^j
> \end{align*}
>   and obtain with $n_0:= 1$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{D_x^m(t(x))^j}&
> =D_x^m{\left.\left(\sum_{k=0}^Nn_kx^k\right)^j\right|_{x=0}}\\
> &=\left.D_x^m\left(\sum_{k_0+k_1+\cdots+k_N=j}\binom{j}{k_0,k_1,\ldots,k_N}
> \prod_{l=1}^N\left(n_lx^l\right)^{k_l}\right)\right|_{x=0}\\
> &=\left.D_x^m\left(\sum_{k_0+k_1+\cdots+k_N=j}\binom{j}{k_0,k_1,\ldots,k_N}
> \left(\prod_{l=1}^Nn_l^{k_l}\right)x^{\sum_{i=1}^Ni\cdot k_i}\right)\right|_{x=0}\\
> &=\left.\sum_{k_0+k_1+\cdots+k_N=j}\binom{j}{k_0,k_1,\ldots,k_N}
> \prod_{l=1}^Nn_l^{k_l}\left(\sum_{l=1}^Nl k_l\right)^{\underline{m}}x^{\left(\sum_{i=1}^Ni\cdot k_i\right)-m}\right|_{x=0}\tag{8}\\
> &\color{blue}{=m!\sum_{{k_0+k_1+\cdots+k_N=j}\atop{k_1+2k_2+\cdots+Nk_N=m}}\binom{j}{k_0,k_1,\ldots,k_N}
> \prod_{i=1}^Nn_i^{k_i}}\tag{9}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (8) we differentiate $m$ times. We use the notation $z^{\underline{m}}=z(z-1)\cdots(z-m+1)$ and observe when evaluating the expression at $x=0$ we have terms unequal to zero only when the following holds
  \begin{align*}
  k_1+2k_2+\cdots+Nk_N=m
  \end{align*}
  In this case the product $\left(\sum_{l=1}^Nl k_l\right)^{\underline{m}}$ simplifies to $m!$.

> **Example:** We can now explicitly do the preparatory work (7) using formula (9).
>
> We obtain with $m=3$ and $t(x)=1+n_1x+n_2x^2+n_3x^3$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{D_x^3(t(x))}&=3!\sum_{{k_0+k_1+k_2+k_3=1}\atop{k_1+2k_2+3k_3=3}}\binom{1}{k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3}
> \left(\prod_{i=1}^3n_i^{k_i}\right)\\
> &=6\binom{1}{0,0,0,1}n_3\\
> &\color{blue}{=6n_3}\\
> \color{blue}{D_x^3(t(x))^2}&=3!\sum_{{k_0+k_1+k_2+k_3=2}\atop{k_1+2k_2+3k_3=3}}\binom{2}{k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3}
> \left(\prod_{i=1}^3n_i^{k_i}\right)\\
> &=6\left(\binom{2}{0,1,1,0}n_1n_2+\binom{2}{0,0,0,1}n_3\right)\\
> &\color{blue}{=12(n_1n_2+n_3)}\\
> \color{blue}{D_x^3(t(x))^3}&=3!\sum_{{k_0+k_1+k_2+k_3=3}\atop{k_1+2k_2+3k_3=3}}\binom{3}{k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3}
> \left(\prod_{i=1}^3n_i^{k_i}\right)\\
> &=6\left(\binom{3}{1,1,1,0}n_1n_2+\binom{3}{2,0,0,1}n_3+\binom{3}{0,3,0,0}n_1^3\right)\\
> &\color{blue}{=6\left(6n_1n_2+3n_3+n_1^3\right)}\\
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with the results in (7).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. It is pretty along what I thought it should be. The only thing that's missing is a general expression for the prepatory work. Maybe the powers of $t(x)$ in terms of multinomials...?

Comment: @PeterSheldrick: Many thanks Peter for this really big bounty! :-)

Comment: perfect thanks. Any idea how the mentioned Bell polynomials fit in here? And what a great reference. Thanks for that as well...

Comment: @draks: Check and compare formula 3.74 in the cited reference. I've played in *[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045505/any-ideas-on-how-i-can-prove-this-expression/1100386#1100386)* rather extensively with Bell polynomials which might be interesting.

Comment: wow, looks like you had fun back then. I'll have a look...

Comment: Not sure if you're interested, but the motivation for the question was a graph theoretical one. Will Orrick gave a nice relation between two forms of Ihara's $\zeta$ function (on a specific example graph) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2225276/19341) (last equation). Your answer could be used to generalize this for other graphs and to understand how closed nonbacktracking tailless paths are counted...

Comment: @draks...: Thanks for the hint. It looks quite interesting. But at the time my focus is on other problems.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help...

Comment: One last thing, because I think I see that Eq. $(9)$ **is** a Bell polynomial: $\displaystyle m!B_{m,j}(n_1,n_2,...)=m!\sum_{{k_0+k_1+\cdots+k_N=j}\atop{k_1+2k_2+\cdots+Nk_N=m}}\binom{j}{k_0,k_1,\ldots,k_N}
\prod_{i=1}^Nn_i^{k_i}$, right?

Comment: @draks...: Good observation! :-) It's a *[partial ordinary Bell polynomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Ordinary_Bell_polynomials)*.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different from Peter's answer. From $$f(x)=\log{\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^Nn_kx^k\right)}=\log{g(x)} \Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \Rightarrow f'g=g'$$ 
With the latter, applying  [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) and considering $g(0)=1$, a pattern emerges and binomial coefficients. For example:

**Case $m=1$**
$$f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \Rightarrow f'(0)=\frac{g'(0)}{g(0)}=n_1$$
**Case $m=2$**
$$f'g=g' \Rightarrow f''g+f'g'=g'' \Rightarrow f''(0)+n_1^2=2n_2$$
$$f''(0)=2n_2-n_1^2$$
**Case $m=3$**
$$f''g+f'g'=g'' \Rightarrow f^{(3)}g+2f''g'+f'g''=g^{(3)} \Rightarrow f^{(3)}(0)+2(2n_2-n_1^2)n_1+2n_1n_2=3\cdot2n_3$$
$$f^{(3)}(0)=2n_1^3-6n_1n_2+6n_3$$
**Case $m=4$**
$$f^{(3)}g+2f''g'+f'g''=g^{(3)} \Rightarrow f^{(4)}g+3f^{(3)}g'+3f''g''+f'g^{(3)}=g^{(4)}$$
and so on. Now we can define two sequences
$$g_n=g^{(n)}(0),g_0=g(0)=1,g_1=g'(0)=n_1$$
$$f_n=f^{(n)}(0),f_0=f(0)=0,f_1=f'(0)=n_1$$
$$g_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\binom{n}{k} f_{n-k+1}g_{k}\right)=f_{n+1}g_{0}+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\binom{n}{k} f_{n-k+1}g_{k}\right)$$
or 
$$f_{n+1}=g_{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\binom{n}{k} f_{n-k+1}g_{k}\right)=g_{n+1}-n\cdot n_1\cdot f_n-n_1\cdot g_n-\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\left(\binom{n}{k} f_{n-k+1}g_{k}\right)$$
Result is, there is no need to compute derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ directly and $g(x)$ is a polynomial whose derivatives are easier to calculate.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is there an easy way to see how it relates to Markus' answer?

Comment: I am not sure, because approaches are different. Both Markus and Peter started by exploiting the composition with quite generic tools (unbound to any particular case) to end up with a relation which contains only powers and derivatives of $t(x)$ polynomial (or $g(x)$ in my notation). I tried to reduce the problem to a recurrence exploiting the particular result of $f'g=g'$.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) the $n$th derivative is expressible as a sum of bell polynomials. In sympy for your example:

```
from sympy import *

x,n1,n2,n3=symbols('x,n1,n2,n3')

def f(x):
    return -log(x)
def g(x):
    return n3*x**3+n2*x**2+n1*x+1

n = 3;

print
print diff(f(g(x)),x,n).subs(x,0)

v = map(lambda k: diff(g(x),x,k).subs(x,0), range(1,n+1))
s = 0
for k in range(1,n+1):
    s +=diff(f(x),x,k).subs(x,g(0))*bell(n,k,v)
print s
```

In this case

```
diff(g(x),x,k)
```

evaluates to $n_1 + 2n_2x + 3n_3x^2$ for $k=1$, $2n_2 + 6n_3x$ for $k=2$, $6n_3$ for $k=3$ and $0$ for $k\geq4$. Setting $x=0$ we get $(g'(0),g''(0),\dots,g^{(n-k+1)}(0))=(n_1,2n_2,6n_3,0,\dots,0)$. Replace the code for $v$ with

```
 v=n*[0];
 v[0]=n1;v[1]=2*n2;v[2]=6*n3;
```

Furthermore since $f'(x)=-1/x$, $f''(x)=+1/x^2$, $f'''(x)=-2/x^3\dots$ and $g(0)=1$ the line

```
 s +=diff(f(x),x,k).subs(x,g(0))*bell(n,k,v)
```

is equivalent to

```
 s +=(-1)^k*factorial(k-1)*bell(n,k,v)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the bounty and your answer. I still have to work thru it...

Comment: @PeterSheldrick: I've added a formula to support the preparatory work in my answer which might be useful.

Comment: Hi, I think I found the relation to the Bell polynomials, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228226/what-is-the-mth-derivative-of-log-left1-sum-limits-k-1n-n-kxk-right#comment4625458_2246991)...

Answer (score 1):

The following is in terms of formal power series. I don't bother about convergence radii.

Assume that the functions $f(x)=\sum_{l\geq 0} f_l x^l$ and $q(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}q_kx^k$, $q_0=1$,  are related by
$$f(x)=\log q(x)\ .\tag{1}$$
Then $f_0=0$, and $(1)$ implies $$q(x)f(x)=q'(x)\ ,$$
or unpacked:
$$\sum_{k\geq0}q_kx^k\cdot\sum_{l\geq 1}l f_l x^{l-1}=\sum_{r\geq1}r q_r x^{r-1}\ .$$
This can be written as
$$\sum_{r\geq0}\left(\sum_{k+l=r} q_k(l+1)f_{l+1}\right)x^r=\sum_{r\geq0}(r+1)q_{r+1} x^r\ ,$$
and comparing coefficients leads to
$$\sum_{k+l=r}q_k(l+1)f_{l+1}=(r+1)q_{r+1}\qquad(r\geq0)\ .$$We now take the summand $k=0$, $l=r$ out of the sum on the left hand side and so obtain the following recursion for the $f_l$:
$$f_{r+1}=q_{r+1}-\sum_{l=1}^r{l\over r+1} q_{r+1-l}\>f_l\qquad(r\geq0)\ .\tag{2}$$

Comment: Does it matter the $q$ is of finite order $N$?

Comment: The sum on the right hand side of $(2)$ has at most $N+1$ terms in this case, even for large $r$. Maybe one would reindex it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You've rediscovered the classical Faber polynomials, presented in OEIS [A263916](https://oeis.org/A263916).

Comment: +1 Interesting, does this information helps to tackle the follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2249648/19341

Comment: In fact you say that $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\log(1+\sum_{k=1}^N n_kx^k)\Biggr|_{x=0}= m!\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j} B_{m,j}(n_1,n_2,...)=F_m(n_1,n_2,...n_k)$ right?

Comment: @draks, I don't have the time to check everything right now. Maybe later. Certainly you can do a sanity check yourself for the first few orders of the partitions, and there is much info in the relevant OEIS entries and links.